# Integration of Infinitesimal Canonical Transformation

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, time, hamiltonian-formalism, integration

Let us assume that the transformation $\underline{\zeta(t_0)} \to \underline{\zeta(t)}$ is canonical and suppose that an Infinitesimal Canonical Transformation (i.e. something like $\underline{\eta} \to \underline{\eta} + \delta \underline{\eta}$) satisfies the symplectic condition (i.e. the jacobian of the transformation is [symplectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix)).

Then, how can we show, by integrating with respect to time over a sequence of ICT's, that the initial tranformation also satisfies the symplectic condition?

So far I have only been able to see that we may need to write something like:
$$\int_{t_0}^{t} \frac{d}{d\tau}\underline{\zeta}(\tau) d \tau = \underline{\zeta}(t) - \underline{\zeta}(t_0)$$
where we may need to recognize a suitable ICT by using the fact that the derivative is connected with first-order approximation.

Does anyone know how to proceed from here?

---

As always, any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

As

Comment: Is the derivative inside your integral supposed to be with respect to $\tau$?

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Yes, but it is just another way of writing the time since otherwise it could be confused with the limits of integration.